# How to get urls by regex c++?

Tags: c++, regex

I can't parse all url's from string. I want to push all url's to array.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

void checkString(std::string x,std::regex e){
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex_search (x,m,e);
  std::cout<<m.position(0);
}
void run(void){
    std::regex e("((https)|(http))\:\/\/media.discordapp.net\/.*\.(((png)|(gif))|((jpeg)|(jpg)))");

    std::string example="dadasdasdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.pngdsdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.gifsdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpegsddshttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpg";

    checkString(example,e);
}
```

I expect the output of:
https://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.png 
https://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.gif 
https://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpeg 
https://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpg

Comment: I would use `R"((?:https|http):\/\/media\.discordapp\.net\/.*?\.(?:png|gif|jpeg|jpg))"` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ThKVy/1)

Comment: unfortunately not working<br>
<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/539138991031844864/598643321115508767/Screenshot_18.png"  width="100" height="600">

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do:

```cpp
void checkString(std::string x,std::regex e){
    std::smatch m;

    while (regex_search(x, m, e))
    {
        std::cout << m.str() << '\n';
        x = m.suffix();
    }
}

int main(){
    std::regex e(R"((?:https|http):\/\/media\.discordapp\.net\/.*?\.(?:png|gif|jpeg|jpg))");

    std::string example="dadasdasdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.pngdsdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.gifsdhttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpegsddshttps://media.discordapp.net/Js1VPuxC5xs.jpg";

    checkString(example,e);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f99bd7e278f59537)

Comment: But my compiller say "identifier  R not defined"

Comment: I did it "((?:https|http):\\/\\/media\\.discordapp\\.net\\/.*?\\.(?:png|gif|jpeg|jpg))" without raw string literal and it worked.